# mysql replication single master and multiple slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I have created a master slave replication on rhel7 with mysql version 5.7 .Now i want to add another slave machine in this replication.Kindly suggest .

1: Do i again need to grant replication privilege for my second_slave server from master server?

2: I have also updated the my.cnf file in second_slave with server-id=3 
   Master: server-id=1
   First_Slave: server-id=2`

Comment: Do you mean the `change master`-command? Yes, you have to do it again. Your server-ids are correct. Is something not working?

Comment: Now everything is working fine i just give the replication privilege to the second slave server also .By using following command  grant replication slave on *.* to root@'172.22.33.%' identified by 'pwd@12';